# How to make transparent to second View controller using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have really trouble to make transparent a view controller. I have 2 view controller. and trying to make transparent second view controller.

This is my first view controller.

```
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let destViewController : SearchViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchViewController") as! SearchViewController
    destViewController.getSearchTxt = self.tagsData[indexPath.row]
   // destViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
      destViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(destViewController, animated: true)
```

this is my second view controller.

```
 self.view.isOpaque = false
    self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

**black background is displaying instead of trasparent**

Comment: try this destViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.31) and delete the self.view.backgroundcolor from there

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen it is not working. if i am using presentController then it is working. but i need to use navigation controller for back button.

Comment: i guess it will not work with navigation controller. if you still want to achieve embed the controller to navigation and present that controller. so you can set a bar button item in navigation item and you can close it

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen may you please tell me how i can do that?

Comment: @user1629977 Transparent background only you can achieve by a present controller and Add a custom button in that ViewController for dismissing it.

Comment: embed viewcontroller before presenting    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destViewController)
        present( destViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen thank you too much it is working. ) +1

Answer (score 1):

For `UINavigationController` displaying `.overCurrentContext` is impossible. If you want to display it overCurrentContext use present

```
self.present(destViewController, animated: true)
```

If `pushViewController` is really required you can try to save the previous view to image and add it as a subview to the new `SearchViewController.view`.